# jQuery Mobile+ PhoneGap split view Issue on screen resolution of Apple iPad & Galaxy tab 

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova, android

I have developed a **Phone Gap application using jQuery mobile**..

I have implemented **`split view in jQuery mobile`** using split view plugin by ***asyraf9***.

by follow the link https://github.com/asyraf9/jquery-mobile/

*`Split view works perfectly with two panes (left and right)`* in **Apple iPad**,

But in **Galaxy Tab**.  *`split view not works it displays only the right panel`*.

what is the problem is there any differences in screen resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in the splitview library that checks if the browser should have splitview enabled or not:

```
var $query = $.mobile.media('screen and (min-width: 480px)') && ($.mobile.media('(-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.2)') || $.mobile.media('(max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.2)'));
$.support.splitview = ($query || ($.mobile.browser.ie && $(this).width() >= 480)) && $.mobile.ajaxEnabled;
```

Here's a text description of what the requirements are (taken from commit log):

> Ajax should be enabled
>
> Pixel to CSS pixel density should be below 1.2,
> we want to avoid having split view in high density devices

The problem you have is not with the resolution (both devices display at least 480px) but the pixel density (linked to pixel ratio).

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Samsung) and what you describe, your samsung tab might be an old one with a 1.5 css pixel ratio, which means it won't have the split view enabled.

If you don't want this behaviour, change the code in jquery.mobile.splitview.js to [bump the max pixel ratio from 1.2 to 2.2](http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/03/jquery-mobile-splitview-fix-for-the-new-ipad/).